# From a C# MVC controller action, is it possible to execute a gulp task

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js, sass, gulp

From a C# MVC controller action, is it possible to execute a gulp task and if so how would I go about doing this?

In my C# app, I'm trying to check if a given string (submitted in a form) is valid sass. 
There are a couple of C# CSS parsers but I can't find one that can handle sass (*.scss).

In my projects I use a gulp task that compiles sass and reports any errors so I was wondering if there was a way I could utilize this to do the validation in my C# app i.e. add the text input from my C# app to a .scss file, get the gulp task to try and compile it, if it passes without errors then I know the sass is valid.

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree here but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want C# to call Node to run a Gulp task to run a Ruby command to compile your SCSS file?

Comment: No, I just want to check that a string submitted in a form in my MVC app is valid sass. And I'm using gulp-sass, not ruby. But I know it's a roundabout way to do things so if anyone has a better solution I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Ahh you're using the one that is out of date and doesn't support the new syntax. Fair enough. You would need to start a process to execute the command and capture the result from the output window to validate it.

Comment: We recently switched to gulp-sass. Using Web Workbench for our sass (which uses ruby I think) was taking about 5 seconds on each save to compile the sass which is a pain if you're doing a lot of frontend work. Now with gulp sass a compile is done in milliseconds. But getting back to the point, I'm not trying to compile the sass for my project. I have built a site so I have a quick reference to things I use and create, for example mixins. I want to be able to add a mixin from the web page hence the mvc app and form submission. How do I start a process to execute the gulp task?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There's a few things here (in your question) that a scaring the absolute crap out of me but I think the easiest summary of it is this :-

> Given an ASP.NET `MVC Controller`, how can I call -another- .exe
>   process?

So assuming you still want to do this, ignoring security vun's and stuff (I'll just roll with you, here...) I think you need to run a new `AppDomain` and then in that app domain run your exe. If the exe fails, you can then capture the error message also.

**Updated as per comments**

<strike>[Random code taken from first'ish google result](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/539195/Run-exe-inside-ASP-NET-and-catch-exception-using-A):</strike>

```
try
{
    //Create a new appdoamin for execute my exe in a isolated way.
    AppDomain sandBox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandBox");
    try
    {
        //Exe executing with arguments
        sandBox.ExecuteAssembly(".exe file name with path");
    }
    finally
    {
        AppDomain.Unload(sandBox);//destry created appdomain and memory is released.
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)//Any exception that generate from executable can handle
{
    //Logger.log(ex.Message);
}
```

so here, you would run the `gulp.exe` and pass in your command line args, include the sass content (content saved to a file?).

Now, if the `.exe` isn't a .NET assembly, then you might need to use the `Process` method...

something like this.. (pseudo code)

```
Process app = new Process();
app.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:/Path to /My/Program to be run.exe";
app.Start();
```

Again - not testing, but this should be enough to get you started...

**Do note** -> running a Process requires serious security permissions on the server, so generally hosted servers (like Azure Websites Site etc) lock all this down to protected themselves. If you own the server, then go nuts.

Final Note:

1. I've never seen or used Node.
2. I've never seen or used gulp.

Comment: You don't need an appdomain. Node is not a .NET process, so there's nothing to gain - just start it as an external process. The separate process will give you more security sandboxing than an appdomain will (process is a security boundary, appdomain is not).